# Overheating on VAIO SB36

Tags: ati, fan, vaio, overheating

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my VAIO SB36 and it overheats and the fan speed is at max.  How should I fix it?

System Specs:

> Intel® Core™ i5-2430M CPU
>
> Unknown graphic detects! (it's both intel and ATI 6470M)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I really do not think it an OS problem, and I do not think its normal either. A friend of mine has the same laptop, with Windows 7, and has the same problem.

It is known that the Vaio SB suffers from heat and noise problems.  As powerful hardware and thin profile don’t go hand in hand. The fans will be particularly noticeable when using the dedicated video card.  But if gets way too hot, I would call Sony, to see what they say about it.

Comment: I don't think so!in win 7 it's cool and doesn't have this problem.

Comment: The guy is setting next to me, and his machine is very hot to the touch, and it sounds like it about to take off..

Comment: that's his problem!!Now I have Mint 13 and don't have any problems...Even in win 7 with 4 open VS 2010 and Gtalk, chrome .... still cool :P

Comment: I`m glad the your is OK :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the overheating problem in Ubuntu is related to the graphic card, and in your case, you have an Hybrid graphic card with the open source drivers. In this case, by default, you have both graphic cards connected but you are only using the integrated (Intel). If you want to use only one and when you want, you need to install the privative drivers following this answer:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124292/153260)

And using the latest driver:

(6 jun) http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip

Comment: This worked to me because I have a HP Pavilion dv6 6c13ss with ATI Radeon HD 7690M XT and Intel HD Graphics 3000 and the latest driver fixed the overheating problem when I enable the powersave graphic card (the integrated one, Intel).