# Ubuntu 12.10 detecting wrong graphics card

Tags: ati, graphics

I have just done a fresh install of 12.10 on my laptop details are below and it is detecting the wrong graphics cards so now the fan is running very loud.

If any could help me I would be very thankful

HP Pavilion dv6-6b05tx Entertainment Notebook PC2nd generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670M Processor (2.2GHz, Dual Core, 4T, 6MB L3)8GB DDR3 RAM 750GB SATA HDD Blu-ray ROM DVD+/-R/RW SuperMulti DL Drive 15.6 inch (1920 x 1080) LED Backlit BrightView display ATI Radeon HD 6770M (2 GB dedicated)

Comment: the graphic card that is using is some intel graphic card maybe from the processor

Comment: have you installed the proprietary gpu drivers? If not, click the dash and search for "Software Properties", then click on the "Additional Drivers" tab in the Software Sources menu and install "fglrx-experimental-X driver"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two graphics cards? One onboard and one discrete? Or what do you mean with "detecting the wrong one"? Is it just the fans, or is the unit getting hot as well?

Linux has still trouble with laptops having hybrid graphics, but you can try a few things with `vgaswitcheroo`, if you have two graphics cards.

Answer (score 0):

As I said here:
[Overheating on VAIO SB36](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145557/overheating-on-vaio-sb36/305021#305021)

> Usually, the overheating problem in Ubuntu is related to the graphic
>   card, and in your case, you have an Hybrid graphic card with the open
>   source drivers. In this case, by default, you have both graphic cards
>   connected but you are only using the integrated (Intel). If you want
>   to use only one and when you want, you need to install the privative
>   drivers following this answer:
>
> [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124292/153260)
>
> And using the latest driver:
>
> (6 jun)
>   http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip